# this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/designRequestlist']); in then of firebase giving errors

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am using angular2-modal that is  this.modal.alert() its working fine

but when I add this line `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/designRequestlist']);` in then of firebase its giving errors

> error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error Error

and

> zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Dialog was forced to close by
>   an unknown source. ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

I want to chnage routing URL after click  **OK** of **this.modal.alert()**

```
editDesignReq = (key, projectTitle, designBrief, projectBudget, timeToEnd) => {
    timeToEnd = (this.addHours * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (timeToEnd);
    this.item.update(key, { projectTitle: projectTitle, designBrief: designBrief, projectBudget: projectBudget, timeToEnd: timeToEnd }).then(() => {

      this.modal.alert()
        .title('Updated.')
        .body('Your Design Brief is updated successfully.')
        .open();
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/designRequestlist']);
    });
    this.addHours = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://plnkr.co/edit/DnVmSqxp5Iv52YTfh1ui?p=preview

Comment: read this https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/blob/master/QUICKTHROUGH.md